# Php adodb CacheExecute com_exception arguments wrong type

Tags: php, adodb

I'm trying to get ADODB caching to work. I have a php script where i define the DB connection.

```
global $conn;
$conn = new COM ("ADODB.Connection");
$connStr = "PROVIDER-SQLOLEDB;SERVER=;UID=;PWD=;DATABASE=);
$conn->open($connStr);
```

I left the unnecessary details out of the picture.

Then in some other script i import the connection.php, and then try to make a normal query.

```
$query = "SELECT * from table where some_id = 21540 and other_id = BOGUS_INFO"
$rs = $GLOBALS['conn']->CacheExecute(60,$query);
```

This returns Uncaught exception 'com_exception'.. ADODB.Connection Arguments are of the wrong type,are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with another.

I'm baffled because the next line of code works flawlessly.

```
$rs = $GLOBALS['conn']->execute($query); //OK!
```

Any ideeas?
I also tried CacheGetOne but i get the same error.
Could it be from the way i defined this thing below? (it's literally like that in my code)

```
$GLOBALS['ADODB_CACHE_DIR']=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../cache/adodb';
```

Answer (score 0):

Well after alot of hassle, i kinda found an answer by choosing another way of doing things. I downloaded the latest ADODB build. Inserted it in my project, and modified files accordingly:

The connection.php changed to:

```
require('PATH/adodb.inc.php');
require('PATH/adodb-csvlib.inc.php');//read somewhere that i need this for the caching executes
$GLOBALS['ADODB_CACHE_DIR'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cache/adodb';
global $ADODB_CACHE_DIR; //don't know which one adodb usese really to identify cache directory so for safety - both
$ADODB_CACHE_DIR = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cache/adodb';
$conn = NewADOConnection('mssqlnative');//i tried first with mssql simple but script terminated execution on execute() attempt.. no error.. no nothing.. no output .. strange
$conn->Connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass, $myDb);
```

After that i had to fiddle a bit with the code because,

```
$rs = $conn->CacheExecute(time,query)
```

returns Adodbrecordset_array_mssqlnative Object, and not an array, and, in my code i used to display and manipulate values as

```
while (!$rs->EOF) {
$rs['row']->value;
$rs->MoveNext();
}
```

and now they should be

```
$rs->fields['row'];
```

Another tricky thing was getting the fields array to be associated to the names of the columns in my query, but after a short search i discovered

```
$GLOBALS['conn']->SetFetchMode(ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC);
```

and voila! Everything works, even the caching.
It took script execution times with this bare optimisation from 1 sec to 0.1 or even 0.005 sometimes.